How to detect the trend change in the script 2BARBLR1.1
I'm using Tradingview and trying to learn pinescript. I'm using the script 2BARBL R1.1
It has a trend line the displays the trend in green for an up trend and red for a down trend. I'm new to pinescript but I'd like to figure out how I can detect the trend ribbon color change from green to red. I want to add a sell label at that bar index. This script was written in ver 3 so I don't think labels are supported. I'm guessing I will need to add a plotchar() to mark the point for the 'sell' character?
I'm NOT asking for anyone to write the code for me. I'm asking for someone to point me in the right direction in the script. Once I know the area in the script to target, I think I can complete the task. Also if someone can confirm that I will need to use the plotchar() to do this?
I believe the plot() at line 223 is where I would need to be looking. If someone can confirm that for me? I have tried to add a plotchar but it didn't work:
a = ""
if tDirection == UP
    a = 'u'
if tDirection == DOWN
    a = 'd'
pct = close
plotchar(pct, char=a, location=location.belowbar, color=#ffff00)

//@version=3
//

study(title="Two Bar Break Line Alerts R1.1 by JustUncleL", shorttitle="2BARBL R1.1", overlay=true,max_bars_back=200)

//
// Author:  JustUncleL
// Date:    25-Mar-2018
// Version: R1.1
//
// Description:
//    This indicator with default settings is designed for BINARY OPTIONS trading. The
//    indicator can also be used for Forex trading with some setting changes. 
//    The script shows Two Bar Pullback Break lines and alerts when those Break lines
//    are Touched (broken) creating a short term momentum entry condition.
//    
//    - For a Bullish Break Out (Green Up Arrow) to occur: first must have two (or three)
//      consecutive bear (red) candles which is followed by a bull (green) candle creating
//      a pivot point. The breakout occurs when the High of the current Bull (green)
//      exceeds the highest point of the previous two (or three) pivotal bear candles. The
//      green channel Line shows where the current Bullish BreakOut  occurs.
//    
//    - For a Bearish Break Out (Red Down Arrow) to occur: first must have two (or three)
//      consecutive bull (green) candles which is followed by a bear (red) candle creating
//      a pivot point. The breakout occurs when the Low of the current Bear (red)
//      drops below the lowest point of the previous two (or three) pivotal Bull candles. The
//      red channel Line shows where the current Bearish BreakOut occurs.
//    
//    The break Line Arrows can optionally be filtered by the Coloured MA (enabled by default), 
///   a longer term directional MA (disabled by default) and/or a MACD condition (enabled by default)
//    as a momentum filter.
//
//    You can optionally select three Bar break lines instead of two. The three bar break lines 
//    are actually equivalent to Guppy's Three Bar Count Back Line method for trade entries 
//    (see Guppy's video reference below).
//
//    Included in this indicator is an ability to display some basic Binary Option statistics, 
//    when enabled (disabled by default) it shows Successful Bars in Yellow and 
//    failed Bars in Black and the last Nine numbers on the script title line 
//    represent the Binary option Statistics in order:
//      - %ITM rate, 
//        Total orders, Successful Orders, Failed Orders,
//        Total candles tested, Candles per Day, Trades per Day, 
//        Max Consecutive Wins, Max Consecutive Losses
//
//    You can start the Binary Option statistics from a specific Date, 
//    which is handy for checking more recent history.
//
// Hints:
//    - BINARY OPTIONS trading: use 5min, 15m, 1hr or even Daily charts. Trade after 
//      the price touches one of the Breakout lines and the Arrow first appears. 
//      Wait for the price to come back from Break Line by 1 or 2 pips, the alert arrow 
//      must stay on and candle change to black, then take Binary trade expiry End of Candle.
//      If price pull back and arrow turns off, don't trade this candle, move on you probably
//      don't have momentum, there will be plenty of other trigger events. 
//      From my backtesting the results are good with ITM rates 65% to 72% on many
//      currency pairs, commodities and indices. Realtime trading has confirmed the
//      the backtesting results and they could even be bettered, provided 
//      you are selective on which signals to trade (strong MACD support etc), 
//      that you are patient and disciplined to this trading method.
//
//    - FOREX trading: the default settings should work with scalping. For longer term trades
//      try with settings change to a more standard MACD filter or slower
//      to catch the longer term momentum swings and the idea would be to trade the 
//      first Break Line alert that occurs after a decent Pullback in the direction 
//      of the trend. Setting the SL to just above/below the Pivot High/Low and 
//      set target to two or three times SL.
//
// References:
//    - "Fundamentals of Price Action Trading for Forex, Stocks, Options and Futures" video:
//          https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4MWUOAAYGIs 
//    - Other videos by "basecamptrading" on Naked Trading.
//    - "Taking Profits in Today's Market by Daryl Guppy" video: 
//          https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QInB6iExaxw
//
// Modifications:
//    R1.0  April-2018
//         - First Published Version
//    R1.1  June-2019 
//         - Added alarms for Trend Direction change and optional direction arrows.
//
//
//
// -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Copyright 2018 JustUncleL
//
// This program is free software: you can redistribute it and/or modify
// it under the terms of the GNU General Public License as published by
// the Free Software Foundation, either version 3 of the License, or
// any later version.
//
// This program is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
// but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
// MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the
// GNU General Public License for more details.
// 
// The GNU General Public License can be found here
// <http://www.gnu.org/licenses/>.
//
// -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
//

//
// === INPUTS START

//
boBars      = input(2,minval=2,maxval=3,title="Use 2 or 3 Bar Break Line Strategy")
hidefractals= input(true,title="Hide Pivot Point Symbols (triangles)")
hidelevels  = input(false,title="Hide Break Out Levels Channel")
maxtrigger  = input(0,minval=0,title="Maximum Trigger Distance from Pivot (0 = no limit)")
cmafilter   = input(true,title="Use Coloured MA Filter on 2Bar Break Outs")
stffilter_  = input(false,title="Use Slow Trend MA Filter on 2Bar Break Outs")
stffilter   = cmafilter? stffilter_ : false
cmaType     = input(defval="HullMA", title="Coloured MA Type: ", options=["SMA", "EMA", "WMA", "VWMA", "SMMA", "DEMA", "TEMA", "HullMA", "ZEMA", "TMA", "SSMA"], type=string)
cmaLen      = input(defval=21, title="Coloured MA Length :", minval=1)
filterType  = input(defval="EMA", title="Slow Trend Filter MA Type: ", options=["SMA", "EMA", "WMA", "VWMA", "SMMA", "DEMA", "TEMA", "HullMA", "ZEMA", "TMA", "SSMA"], type=string)
filterLen   = input(defval=200, title="Slow Trend Filter MA Length :", minval=1)
//
show2Balert = input(true, title="Show Bar Break Alert Arrors")
showCCalert = input(false, title="Show MA Direction Alert Arrows")

//
// Get MACD for Alert Filtering
umacd       = input(true,title="Use MACD Filter on 2Bar Break Outs")
signalFilter_= input(true, title="Use MACD Signal Line instead of Above/Below Zero for filter")
MACDfast    = input(title="MACD Fast MA Length", type = integer, defval = 8, minval = 2)
MACDslow    = input(title="MACD Slow MA Length", type = integer, defval = 21, minval = 7)
MACDsignal  = input(title="MACD Signal Length",  type = integer, defval = 5 , minval = 1)
src         = close
signalFilter= MACDsignal==1?false:signalFilter_
//
DodgerBlue = #1E90FF
UP = 1
DOWN = -1


// === INPUTS END

// === FUNCTIONS

// - variant(type, src, len)
// Returns MA input selection variant, default to SMA if blank or typo.

// SuperSmoother filter
// © 2013  John F. Ehlers
variant_supersmoother(src,len) =>
    a1 = exp(-1.414*3.14159 / len)
    b1 = 2*a1*cos(1.414*3.14159 / len)
    c2 = b1
    c3 = (-a1)*a1
    c1 = 1 - c2 - c3
    v9 = 0.0
    v9 := c1*(src + nz(src[1])) / 2 + c2*nz(v9[1]) + c3*nz(v9[2])
    v9
    
variant_smoothed(src,len) =>
    v5 = 0.0
    v5 := na(v5[1]) ? sma(src, len) : (v5[1] * (len - 1) + src) / len
    v5

variant_zerolagema(src,len) =>
    ema1 = ema(src, len)
    ema2 = ema(ema1, len)
    v10 = ema1+(ema1-ema2)
    v10
    
variant_doubleema(src,len) =>
    v2 = ema(src, len)
    v6 = 2 * v2 - ema(v2, len)
    v6

variant_tripleema(src,len) =>
    v2 = ema(src, len)
    v7 = 3 * (v2 - ema(v2, len)) + ema(ema(v2, len), len)               // Triple Exponential
    v7
    
// return variant, defaults to SMA 
variant(type, src, len) =>
    type=="EMA"     ? ema(src,len) : 
      type=="WMA"   ? wma(src,len): 
      type=="VWMA"  ? vwma(src,len) : 
      type=="SMMA"  ? variant_smoothed(src,len) : 
      type=="DEMA"  ? variant_doubleema(src,len): 
      type=="TEMA"  ? variant_tripleema(src,len): 
      type=="HullMA"? wma(2 * wma(src, len / 2) - wma(src, len), round(sqrt(len))) :
      type=="SSMA"  ? variant_supersmoother(src,len) : 
      type=="ZEMA"  ? variant_zerolagema(src,len) : 
      type=="TMA"   ? sma(sma(src,len),len) : 
                      sma(src,len)

// - /variant 

// === /FUNCTIONS END

// === SERIES VARIABLES
// 
// Find all Fractals for two or three Bars back.
topfractal = boBars==2? high[1]>high[2] and open[2]<close[2] and open[1]<close[1] and (open>close or high<high[1]) : high[2]>high[3] and high[1]>high[2] and open[1]<close[1] and open>close
botfractal = boBars==2? low[1]<low[2] and open[2]>close[2] and open[1]>close[1] and (open<close or low>low[1]) : low[2]<low[3] and low[1]<low[2] and open[1]>close[1] and open<close

// MA's
ma_slow    = variant(cmaType, src, cmaLen)
ma_filter  = variant(filterType, src, filterLen)

// Get Direction for Moving Averages
slowdirection = UP
slowdirection := ma_slow>ma_slow[1] ? UP : ma_slow<ma_slow[1] ? DOWN : nz(slowdirection[1],UP)
slowdirection := stffilter? slowdirection==UP? (ma_slow>ma_filter? UP : 0)  : slowdirection==DOWN? (ma_slow<ma_filter? DOWN : 0) : slowdirection  : slowdirection
tDirection    = slowdirection

// Get MACD line
[currMacd,signalLine,_] = macd(close, MACDfast, MACDslow, MACDsignal)

// === /SERIES VARIABLES END

// === PLOTTING

plotshape(hidefractals ? na : topfractal, color=red, transp=0, style=shape.triangledown, location=location.abovebar, offset=0, size=size.tiny)
plotshape(hidefractals ? na : botfractal, color=green, transp=0, style=shape.triangleup, location=location.belowbar, offset=0, size=size.tiny)

//
//plot(filter and fastLen>1 and slowLen!=fastLen? ma_fast:na,color=blue,transp=0,linewidth=2,title="Fast MA Filter line")
plot(cmafilter? ma_slow:na,color=tDirection==UP?lime:red,transp=0,linewidth=2,title="Coloured MA Filter line")
plot(stffilter? ma_filter:na,color=gray,transp=0,linewidth=2,title="Slow Trend Filter Line")
// If this is a Pivot point, Find the Breakout trigger Level
toptriggers = 0.0
bottriggers = 0.0
toptriggers := topfractal ? boBars==2?min(low[2],low[1]): min(low[3],min(low[2],low[1])): toptriggers[1]
bottriggers := botfractal ? boBars==2?max(high[2],high[1]): max(high[3],max(high[2],high[1])) : bottriggers[1]

// Find number of bars since last new Pivot point
tcount = barssince(topfractal)
bcount = barssince(botfractal)

// Plot Breakout trigger Levels as a channel
plot(hidelevels ? na : toptriggers, color=red, transp=0,offset=0,style=stepline, linewidth=1,title="Top Breakout Line")
plot(hidelevels ? na : bottriggers, color=lime, transp=0,offset=0,style=stepline, linewidth=1, title="Bottom Breakout Line")


// Check for trigger line break, count bars past trigger line
tup = 0
tdn = 0
tup := high>bottriggers and close>open[1] and open<bottriggers and (maxtrigger==0 or bcount<=maxtrigger) and (not cmafilter or tDirection==UP) ? nz(tup[1])+1 : 0
tup := umacd ? signalFilter ? (signalLine<currMacd ? tup : 0 ) : (currMacd>0 and signalLine<currMacd? tup : 0) : tup
tdn := low<toptriggers and close<open[1] and open>toptriggers and (maxtrigger==0 or tcount<=maxtrigger) and (not cmafilter or tDirection==DOWN) ? nz(tdn[1])+1 : 0
tdn := umacd ? signalFilter ? (signalLine>currMacd ? tdn : 0 ) : (currMacd<0 and signalLine>currMacd? tdn : 0) : tdn
//
plotarrow(not show2Balert? na : tup==1?1:tdn==1?-1:na, minheight=10, maxheight=100, colorup=line, colordown=red, title="Breakout Arrows")

// show trend direction change arrows
tSignal =  change(tDirection) ? tDirection : 0
plotshape(showCCalert and tSignal==UP?   ma_slow : na, style=shape.triangleup,location=location.absolute,size=size.normal, transp=0, color=green, title="MA Direction Arrows")
plotshape(showCCalert and tSignal==DOWN? ma_slow : na, style=shape.triangledown,location=location.absolute,size=size.normal, transp=0, color=maroon, title="MA Direction Arrows")


// === /PLOTTING END

// === ALERTING
buy = tup==1
sell = tdn==1
alertcondition(buy or sell, title="Break Line Alert", message="BL Alert")
alertcondition(buy, title="Break Line BUY", message="BUY")
alertcondition(sell, title="Break Line SELL", message="SELL")
alertcondition(tSignal==UP, title="Trend UP", message="TREND UP")
alertcondition(tSignal==DOWN, title="Trend Down", message="TREND DOWN")

//

// === /ALERTING END

// ===============================================================
// --- STATISTICS ---
// This is a generic piece of code to Generate bar by bar Binary Options statistics
// This idea was inspired by "Binary option trading by two previous bars" by radixvinni
// You can start the statistices from a specific Date, which is handy for checking
// more recent history.
//
// Inputs
ssuc     = input(true,title="Show BinaryOptions Statistics and Highlight Bars")
nc       = input(0,minval=0,title="Number of Candles in BO trade (default=0)")
// Start statistics from this date/time
d_year   = input(2010,minval=1990,    title="Start BO Stats Year")
d_month  = input(1,minval=1,maxval=12,title="Start BO Stats Month")
d_day    = input(1,minval=1,maxval=31,title="Start BO Stats Day")
d_hour   = input(0,minval=0,maxval=23,title="Start BO Stats Hour")
d_minute = input(0,minval=0,maxval=59,title="Start BO Stats Minute")

// Don't count data before this Start time.
isvalid_time = time >= timestamp(d_year, d_month, d_day, d_hour, d_minute) 

 
GRAY = #6969690F
GOLD = #FFD700FF
BLACK= #000000FF
 

//
// Mark alert bars, check and mark trade completed ITM or not
alert_bar = isvalid_time? (buy[nc] or sell[nc]) : false
correct   = alert_bar? (buy[nc] and close > bottriggers[nc]) or  (sell[nc] and (close < toptriggers[nc])): false
 
//
// Show end of trade bar Success(Yellow) or Failure(Black)
bcolor = alert_bar and correct? GOLD: alert_bar==1? BLACK : na
barcolor(ssuc?bcolor:na,title="Successful and Failed Bars")
//
// Count Successes and failuers
wcount = 0
lcount = 0
wmax = 0
lmax = 0
//
yellow_bar = isvalid_time? (alert_bar and correct)?1:0 : 0
black_bar =  isvalid_time? (alert_bar and not correct)?1:0 : 0
all_bar   =  isvalid_time? 1 : 0
//
wcount := yellow_bar? nz(wcount[1])+1 : nz(wcount[1])
wcount := black_bar? 0 : wcount
wmax   := wcount>nz(wmax[1])? wcount : nz(wmax[1])
//
lcount := black_bar? nz(lcount[1])+1 : nz(lcount[1])
lcount := yellow_bar? 0 : lcount
lmax   := lcount>nz(lmax[1])? lcount : nz(lmax[1])
 
//
// Calculate the simple stats
total_bars    = cum(all_bar)
total_yellow_bars = cum(yellow_bar)
total_black_bars = cum(black_bar)
total_trades  = total_yellow_bars + total_black_bars
success_rate  = total_trades>0? 100.0*total_yellow_bars/total_trades: 0
bars_per_day  = isintraday? 1440/interval : 1
trades_per_day= total_trades/(total_bars/bars_per_day) 
//
// Plot dummy shapes, to allow numbers to be displayed as Nine numbers in format line of indicator
plotshape(ssuc?success_rate:na,"success rate",location=location.bottom, color=nz(bcolor,GRAY), style=shape.triangleup,size=size.auto)
plotshape(ssuc?total_trades:na,"trades made",location=location.bottom, color=nz(bcolor,GRAY), style=shape.triangleup,size=size.auto)
plotshape(ssuc?total_yellow_bars:na,"winning trades",location=location.bottom, color=nz(bcolor,GRAY), style=shape.triangleup,size=size.auto)
plotshape(ssuc?total_black_bars:na,"losing trades",location=location.bottom, color=nz(bcolor,GRAY), style=shape.triangleup,size=size.auto)
plotshape(ssuc?total_bars:na,"total bars",location=location.bottom, color=nz(bcolor,GRAY), transp=0, style=shape.triangleup,size=size.auto)
plotshape(ssuc?bars_per_day:na,"bars per day",location=location.bottom, color=nz(bcolor,GRAY), transp=0, style=shape.triangleup,size=size.auto)
plotshape(ssuc?trades_per_day:na,"trades per day",location=location.bottom, color=nz(bcolor,GRAY), transp=0, style=shape.triangleup,size=size.auto)
plotshape(ssuc?wmax:na,"maximum consec wins",location=location.bottom, color=nz(bcolor,GRAY), transp=0, style=shape.triangleup,size=size.auto)
plotshape(ssuc?lmax:na,"maximum consec losses",location=location.bottom, color=nz(bcolor,GRAY), transp=0, style=shape.triangleup,size=size.auto)
 
// --- STATISTICS ---
// ===============================================================

// --- debugs

//plotshape(tcount,location=location.bottom,color=gray)
//plotshape(bcount,location=location.bottom,color=gray)

// --- /debugs


//eof


I am currntly trying the following code but I'm getting the error msg
"Output rm_0 depends on mutable variable. Enclose code with mutable vars in a function call"
data5 = 0
data5 := tDirection > 0 ? "BUY" : "SELL"
plotchar(close, char='', text=data5)

yes. You must first convert the v3 (obsolete) code.
The original code has a typo that prevents conversion.
line 248: change "line" to "lime"
plotarrow(not show2Balert? na : tup==1?1:tdn==1?-1:na, minheight=10, maxheight=100, colorup=lime, colordown=red, title="Breakout Arrows")

Yes. The plot color change is on line 223
tDirection==UP

In plotchar the character must be in quotes
plotchar(pct, char='a', location=location.belowbar, color=#ffff00)

